# How to add custom CSS into a WP theme

Tags: wordpress

Hello i just purchased the WP theme Alona from http://themeforest.net/item/alona-tidy-clean-portfolio/8926976. I installed the theme into wp properly, and it is working, but it seems that i cant make any changes to the style sheet even after altering the preferences to the style sheet on my host. I'm not sure why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you go to the style editor, you are able to change the style.css file. If you don't see changes, try CTRL+F5 to clear your browser cache (CSS goes in cache...)

Answer (score -1):

Most of the purchased theme having Theme options In that you can find space for custom css or advanced css.

```
        Themeoptions->customcss
```

if its not available

you can edit in

```
 apperence->editor->style.css (its not safe)
```

so you should create a

```
   apperence-> child theme->activate it
```

Edit WordPress theme CSS

```
 Appearance → Editor->style.css(child theme).
```

you can change the style of detailed reference [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: I did this but i still cant directly edit the CSS. The stylesheet int the editor is blank.